# Using topojson.py?

Tags: topojson, references

How do I use the topojson.py created by calvinmetcalf: https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/topojson.py

There is a test file at git, which I tried to modify, but unfortunately I don't really know the python syntax.
So I don't know how to initialize the calsses etc.

```
import json
import unittest

from topojson.conversion import convert


class TestTopojson(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        with open(r"C:\Users\root\Desktop\2016\Bundeslaender.geojson") as f:
            self.square_geojson = json.load(f)

    def test_convert_geojson_to_topojson(self):
        tj = convert(self.square_geojson)
        self.assertEqual(tj['type'], 'Topology')



if __name__=="__main__":

    test1 = TestTopojson('test1')
    test1.setUp(test1)
    test1.test_convert_geojson_to_topojson
```

I'm looking for a good and simple step by step tutorial on using the topojson.py classes.
I think that using python would be the best approach to easily convert geojson to topojson on a Windows machine ..

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Comment: I really don't know how to ask this question different ..
It is about how to use the topojson.py (link provided) 
Any suggestions welcome

Answer (score 3):

It's true that is not very clear. A simple example:

```py
from topojson.conversion import convert
from topojson import geojson
import json

with open("test.geojson") as f:
  test_geojson = json.load(f)
print test_geojson
{u'type': u'FeatureCollection', u'features': [{u'geometry': {u'type': u'Polygon', u'coordinates': [[[-83.23145862723665, 42.61719935058299], [-83.2316352368618, 42.61737853618379], [-83.23166951279292, 42.61742295755952], [-83.23119346860754, 42.617678900083554], [-83.23097637034452, 42.6174586310034], [-83.23145862723665, 42.61719935058299]]]}, u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'LOWPARCELID': u'1902226080'}}]}
# to TopoJSON
tj = convert(test_geojson)
print tj
{'objects': {'name': {u'type': 'GeometryCollection', 'geometries': [{u'type': u'Polygon', 'properties': {u'LOWPARCELID': u'1902226080'}, 'arcs': [[0]]}]}}, 'type': 'Topology', 'bbox': [-83.23166951279292, 42.61719935058299, -83.23097637034452, 42.617678900083554], 'arcs': [[[3042, 0], [-2548, 3736], [-494, 926], [6867, 5337], [3132, -4593], [-6957, -5406]]], 'transform': {'translate': [-83.23166951279292, 42.61719935058299], 'scale': [6.932117695749783e-08, 4.795974603069803e-08]}}
# to GeoJSON
print geojson(tj)
{'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': [{'geometry': {'type': u'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[-83.23145863777262, 42.61719935058299], [-83.2316352681315, 42.617378528194166], [-83.23166951279292, 42.617422938918985], [-83.23119348427075, 42.617678900083554], [-83.23097637034452, 42.617458620970034], [-83.23145863777262, 42.61719935058299]]]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {u'LOWPARCELID': u'1902226080'}}]}
```

But it works only with GeoJSON files with a `features` key (FeatureCollection)

```py
test =  { "type": "Polygon",
 "coordinates": [
   [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
   ]
}
tj = convert(test)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "topojson/conversion.py", line 22, in convert
output_dict = topology(input_dict, *args, **kwargs)
File "topojson/topology.py", line 20, in topology
[x0,x1,y0,y1]=bound(objects)
File "topojson/bounds.py", line 20, in bound
b.obj(objects)
File "topojson/mytypes.py", line 46, in obj
self.outObj[fName]=self.FeatureCollection(obj[fName])
File "topojson/mytypes.py", line 19, in FeatureCollection
for feature in collection['features']:
KeyError: 'features'
```

#### New

The result of setup.py build/install is not correct with the setup.py of the git repository

A correct structure for Python 2.7.x is

[image]

The init.py file is [**init**.py](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/topojson.py/blob/master/__init__.py)

Then (with [see](https://github.com/araile/see) "dir for humans")

```py
import topojson
from see import see
see(topojson)
.geojson()     .topojson()
# therefore
from topojson.topojson.conversion import convert
from topojson.geojson import geojson
```

Comment: Well .. I'm still having troubles using the code .. I tried your version and adjustet the test.geojson file to one of mine.
But the errors start at the very beginning, because I'm not able to make the `from topojson import geojson` 
It throws errors at this point. Are you using the git repository I linked above?

Comment: look above for a solution

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. Got it to work right now .. but the library just accept very few geojson formats. I converted a shapefile to geosjon using ogr2ogr and ogr created a very clean and perfect geosjon file .. but the topojson library can't load it .. :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already solved the problem but anyway...

I ported the TopoJSON code from JavaScript to Python, following the exact same format Mike uses in his library (along with his +300 tests).

To perform the conversion from GeoJSON to TopoJSON, just execute:

```py
from pytopojson import topology


test = {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [[100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]]
    ]
}

topology_ = topology.Topology()
topojson = topology_({'my_geojson': test})) # You have to provide a name for the GeoJSON
```

If you print the TopoJSON you will get.

```py
print(topojson)

{
   "type":"Topology",
   "objects":{
      "my_geojson":{
         "type":"Polygon",
         "arcs":[
            [
               0
            ]
         ]
      }
   },
   "arcs":[
      [
         [
            100.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            101.0,
            0.0
         ],
         [
            101.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            100.0,
            1.0
         ],
         [
            100.0,
            0.0
         ]
      ]
   ],
   "bbox":[
      100.0,
      0.0,
      101.0,
      1.0
   ]
}
```

You can also use the command-line tool located in the `bin` folder:

```bsh
python geo2topo.py < geojson_file
```

To install it, you just have to run:

```bsh
pip install pytopojson
```

Let me know if this was helpful to you!